# How to get a function's attributes when passing it as a parameter

Tags: python, lambda

I found out that if you want to pass a function with parameters as a parameter itself you should use lambda functions.

What I want to achieve is that, the evaluate function finds the attributes of the function which have been passed in it's parameter. I suspect it is possible, but I'm not totally familiar with the workings of lambda.

```
def do_something(foo):
"""this functions raises an Exception"""
    print foo
    raise Exception


def evaluate(funct, testname):
"""In this function I want to evaluate by example whether it throws exceptions"""
    try:
        if hasattr(funct, '__call__'):
            funct()
    except Exception:
        print "Error in "+ testname+ " " + funct.__name___ + " " + funct.__doc__
```

by example i would expect a print like this

```
>>>evaluate(lambda: do_something("foo"), "The Test Suite")
foo
Error in The Test Suite do_something this functions raises an Exception
```

Comment: `do_something` never gets called ... You'd need `lambda: do_something()` if you want it to be called -- or just pass `do_something` directly..

Comment: ^^ i edited my question, it was indeed as you said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original code called `evaluate` with a function but no args. When the evaluator called the function, it didn't pass anything.  Consider passing the function (for docs and name), *and* a pre-called function call. Use [partial](http://devdocs.io/python/library/inspect) to encode a function and its parameters in a new object. This means the evaluator can call the function with args, and catch the exception raised.

A simpler version (`evaluate2`) puts the test name first, then the function, then the function's args.  In this way the caller doesn't need to explicitly call `partial()`.

For extra awesomeness, you can print out what the caller passed in, and tons of other valuable information from the traceback.  See: [inspect](http://devdocs.io/python/library/inspect)

### source

```
from functools import partial

def do_something(foo, bar):
    """this function raises an Exception"""
    print foo,bar
    raise Exception('uhoh')

def evaluate(fcall, testname):
    "print message if func call throws exception"
    try:
        fcall()
    except Exception:
        funct = fcall.func
        print ("Error in "+ testname+ " " 
               + funct.__name__ 
               + " " + funct.__doc__
               )

def evaluate2(testname, funct, *args, **kwargs):
    "print message if func call throws exception"
    try:
        funct(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception:
        print ("Error in "+ testname+ " " 
               + funct.__name__ 
               + " " + funct.__doc__
               )

evaluate(partial(do_something, foo='beer'), 'mytest')
evaluate2('mytest2', do_something, 'tasty', foo='beer')
```

### output

```
Error in mytest do_something this function raises an Exception
Error in mytest2 do_something this function raises an Exception
```

Comment: I fear this will increase complexity... The goal of this function is to simplify evaluation of different functions. AND `print myfunc.__doc__` won't return the docstring of reveal_truth

Comment: @studioj I've completely revamped the code and added a new description

Comment: looks good, there is a way to get to the functions doc without passing the function itself which looks cleaner I believe.
`def evaluate(fcall, testname):
    """In this function I want to evaluate by example whether it throws exceptions"""
    if isinstance(funct, partial):
        try:
            fcall()
        except Exception:
            print "Error in "+ testname+ " " + fcall.func.__name__ + " " + fcall.func.__doc__`
if you add this I'll accept the answer :-)

Comment: @studioj updated. I also wrote a simpler version which doesn't require `partial()`, but also changes the API a little.

Comment: I'm using the partial solution, as this separates the function and its args from the other evaluate args and thus defines a more clear differentiation between them

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use lambda functions at all.  If I call

evaluate( do_something, "The Test Suite" )

... I get the output you expect.  As far as I am aware, lambda functions are only a convenience--you can always use a "regular" function instead (and IMHO it is usually more clear to do so).

Comment: indeed I over simplified my question => edit: how would I pass do_something's parameter foo then?

Answer (score 1):

Working off of shavenwarthog's answer, I think you need to supply the arguments to the function in the call to evaluate().  Using functools might not be necessary, though.  Does the following code do what you are looking for?

```
def do_something(foo):
    """this function raises an Exception"""
    print foo
    raise Exception

def do_something_else(foo1, foo2, foo3):
    """this function also raises an Exception"""
    print foo1, foo2, foo3
    raise Exception


def evaluate(funct, args, testname):
    """In this function I want to evaluate by example whether it throws exceptions"""
    try:
        if hasattr(funct, '__call__'):
            funct(*args)
    except Exception:
        print "Error in "+ testname+ " " + funct.__name__ + " " + funct.__doc__



if __name__ == '__main__':
    evaluate( do_something, ("foo",), "The Test Suite")
    evaluate( do_something_else, ("a string", 1, [2,3,4]), "The Test Suite")
```

Comment: This would indeed work also, but it seems less flexible than shavenwarthog 's answer. I'll try both answers before picking a most fitting one